# what is the equivalent group code for nest and group functions in D3 V6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchical-data

I am absolute new to both JavaScript and D3. I have problem to convert below D3 codes from version 3 to 6 .
data:
d2.csv:

```
city,type,price,id
a,c,10,1
a,c,15,2
a,d,30,3
a,d,40,4
a,e,5,5
a,e,10,6
a,e,7,7
b,c,15,8
b,c,20,9
b,d,9,10
b,d,4,11
b,e,12,12
b,e,15,13
```

D3 V3 code:

```js
data = d3.csv('./data/d2.csv', function (data) {
    var nestedData = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) { return d.city; }).sortKeys(d3.descending)
        .key(function (d) { return d.type; }).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .sortValues(function (a, b) { return +b.price - +a.price; })
        .entries(data);
    console.log(nestedData);

})
```

please help me with version 6

Answer (score 2):

You can use the logic of the little helper function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611784/765395) to convert the nested `Map` returned from `d3.group` back into an `Object` with the format you expect per `d3.nest`. This should work for any level of nesting.

To accommodate the sorting logic, use `d3.ascending` and `d3.descending` over the array of objects you get from your CSV before you call `d3.group`.

Working example:

```js
const csv = `city,type,price,id
a,c,10,1
a,c,15,2
a,d,30,3
a,d,40,4
a,e,5,5
a,e,10,6
a,e,7,7
b,c,15,8
b,c,20,9
b,d,9,10
b,d,4,11
b,e,12,12
b,e,15,13`;

// helper function to convert nested Map to {key: x, values: []} format
const mapToObject = (map = new Map) => Array.from(
  map.entries(), 
  ([k, v]) => ({
    "key": k,
    "values": v instanceof Map ? mapToObject(v) : v
  })
);

// get the data and apply the sorting logic
const data = d3.csvParse(csv)
  .sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.city, b.city)
    || d3.ascending(a.type, b.type)
    || d3.descending(+a.price, +b.price));

// call the helper function with output of d3.group
const nestedData = mapToObject(
  d3.group(
    data,
    d => d.city,
    d => d.type
  )
);

// same result as your d3.nest example
console.log(nestedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly on d3 v7 too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [there is no direct equivalent](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide) for `d3.nest` in **V6**. I tried `d3.group` / `d3.groups` / `d3.rollup` but did not get exactly the same result...

Instead, you can use the following code:

```
d3.csv('./data/d2.csv', function (data) {
  const nestedData = data
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.city > b.city) return -1;
      if (a.city < b.city) return 1;
      if(a.type > b.type) return 1; 
      if(a.type < b.type) return -1; 
      return b.price - a.price;
    })
    .reduce((arr, item) => {
      const cityObj = arr.find(({key}) => key === item.city);
      if (!cityObj) {
        arr.push({key: item.city, values: [{key: item.type, values: [item]}]});
        return arr;
      }
      const typeObj = cityObj.values.find(({key}) => key === item.type);
      if (!typeObj) {
        cityObj.values.push({key: item.type, values: [item]});
        return arr;
      }
      typeObj.values.push(item);
      return arr;
    }, []);

  console.log(nestedData);
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/9mvLfug0/) with a tested code.